# Alternative to eval

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, eval

I am making some common function where in I pass the array, name of field from array, value of field in array and return field name to return value as below

```
function arrayFilter(_array, findField, value, returnField) {
 var temp = "_array[i]." + findField;
 var retValue = "";
 for (var i = 0; i < _array.length; i++) {
   if (eval(temp) == value) {
  return eval("_array[i]." + returnField);
  }
 }
}
```

But when I read on Internet I found that eval is not good, it can have string injection attack.

So somebody help on above.

Comment: Have you got an example of the type of array you're looping over?

Comment: I ask only because there have got to be far better ways of doing what you want to do if you restructure your array better.

Comment: I don't really understand why even people ask that. How do they learn about `eval` before extremely basics that is `[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
return eval("_array[i]." + returnField);
```

Try:

```
return _array[i][returnField];
```

And also read [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html#link4).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *square bracket notation* for accessing properties when the value of your *key* is unknown.

```
function arrayFilter(_array, findField, value, returnField) {
 var temp = _array[i][findField];
 var retValue = "";
 for (var i = 0; i < _array.length; i++) {
   if (temp == value) {
     return _array[i][returnField];
   }
 }
}
```